# How to Make custome record view Meter?

Tags: android, audio-recording

i want make custome view meter which is spred when the user record the voice??

Does anyone know of any coding examples of a digital VU Meter for recording audio?

Does anyone know of any coding examples for showing feedback when a recording is being made?

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Mediastore file means Audio Recording .just like click the button and start the recording

```
public class MediastoreActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
startRecording();
}});
}
public void startRecording() {
Intent intt = new Intent("android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND");
startActivityForResult(intt, 0);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 0:
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 Uri recordedAudioPath = data.getData();
}
}
}
}
```

This is a mail.xml file create only one button

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/recordBtn"
android:text="Record Audio"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: HIII Kumar.you r right but i need to spread vu meter when record is start.

Comment: i didnt get what u said. do try this, and do little modificatios. u will get.

Comment: hii kumar.. i am saying that when i start speak the meter is working like when scooter's meter.VU meter is based on db sound.if any code is available then plz tell me

Comment: i am using the same code vu meter is working and click the start button you will speak something it will work check this code

Comment: Hey kumar i have see this and implement this code..in emulator its working but when i am test in real device then i am getting Force close error.. here is my error Log:::